# Tensorflow DeepLab Colab does npt work for image URL

Tags: tensorflow, deeplab

Tensorflow DeepLab colab works for each of the three images listed, but I tried different image URL and it does not seem to work for any - it says it can not find the URL - here is an example.

image URL:
https://www.pexels.com/photo/new-york-street-cabs-taxis-8247/

colab URL:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1j--WwvZTXMxIV76Z2cAuRcGVPXXRjR_S#scrollTo=edGukUHXyymr

Answer (score 0):

never mind the problem is solved, you want to make sure that the image URL has a .jpg extension at the end - then it works.